# Elements of a group than can achieve all orders in its quotients

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. For different purposes I am now interested in a quite natural property that the elements in $G$ may or may not have, and I would like to ask if there is a standard terminology for that.

I say that an element $g\in G$ is *nice* if it has infinite order, and moreover the following holds: for every $k>0$, the image $[g]$ in $G/_{N(g^k)}$ has order $k$ (and not some smaller divisor of $k$). Here $N(g^k)$ is of course the normal closure of $g^k$.

I would like to know if there is some standard terminology, and whether this property has been studied in some cases. I am interested mostly in finitely presented groups.

Some examples:

If $g$ is nice in some quotient of $G$, then it is nice also in $G$.

If $g$ has infinite order in the abelianisation of $G$, then it is nice.

By [This paper of Baumslag, Morgan, and Shalen](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0305004100067013), many elements in the free product of two cyclic groups are nice.

**Edit.** As pointed out by YCor in the comments, $g$ is nice iff all natural numbers may be realised as orders of $[g]$ in some quotient of $G$ (as in the title).

Comment: In other words $g$ is nice iff it has infinite order and $N(g^k)\cap\langle g\rangle=\langle g^k\rangle$ for all $k\ge 1$. If you have to introduce terminology, you should introduce a more robust one. For instance, define $W(g)$ as the set of orders of $g$ in all quotients of $G$. Of course $w(g)$ determines the order of $g$ (it's the lcm of $W(g)$). Then "nice" means that $W(g)=\mathbf{N}$ where $\mathbf{N}$ is the set of nonnegative integers and "infinite order" means "order zero".

Comment: Yep. however I don't see why this should be equivalent to the modified title of the question...

Comment: Yes it's equivalent and and it's immediate. If $g$ is nice, then its image has order $k$ in $G/N(g^k)$. Conversely suppose my condition. For any $k\ge 1$, let $H$ be a quotient of $G$ on which $g$ has order $k$. Then $G\to H$ factors through $G/N(g^k)$. So $g$ also has order $k$ in $G/N(g^k)$.

Comment: The property "nice" is too strong and I do not think it is satisfied very often and deserves a special name. A weaker version is when your property holds for all but finitely many $k$. That is true for very many groups and many elements: all hyperbolic elements in relatively hyperbolic groups, for example. This is proved using the Dehn (peripheral)fillings, see  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510195.pdf .

Comment: You didn't mention it in the question, but presumably you're aware that all (non-trivial) elements of free groups are "nice"?  This is a well known fact about one-relator groups, usually deduced as a consequence of Lyndon's identity theorem. ADDED: On reflection, one should probably think of that as a special case of the Baumslag--Morgan--Shalen result. But they only explicitly consider cyclic groups of finite order, and Lyndon's proof is quite different.

Comment: @MarkSapir that's my all point of defining a "robust" terminology (see my first comment): a terminology that is flexible enough to be adapted. You're defining those $g$ such that $W(g)$ is cofinite. But your comment is also ambiguous because the OP defines a property for the data of a group and an element $g$ of the group, while you define a property for a group which you haven't defined... possibly you mean that every $g$ of infinite order in $G$ has $W(g)$ cofinite, or every $g\neq 1$... of course this is not "robust" since each new variation requires a new definition.

Comment: No, I define a property of an element $g$ of a group $G$: for almost all $k$ the element $g$ in $G/N(g^k)$ has order $k$. That happens, in particular, of $G$ is relatively hyperbolic and $g$ is hyperbolic.

Comment: @HJRW: Lyndon's  result about free groups easily follows from the BMS result because for every element $g$ in the free group $F_n$, $n\ge 2$, there exists a homomorphism from $F_n$ to a free product of finite cyclic groups which maps $g$ to a hyperbolic element. But Lyndon's result was proved earlier.

Comment: @MarkSapir , that’s what I meant in my addition to my comment.